# Package bidi error

Tags: titlesec, overleaf, bidi

I'm having troubles with the following error on latex, i'm working on overleaf.

```
Package bidi Error: Oops! you have loaded package titlesec after bidi package. Please load 
package titlesec before bidi package, and then try to run xelatex on your document again.
```

does nyone have a solution for this ?

Comment: Have you did as the error message instructed and changed the loading order of the named packages?

Comment: @LaccaseTVersicolor the thing is that i don't even have a "bidi package" imported. This is why i found the error confusing

Comment: simply move titlesec up until the error disappears.

Comment: @NadjibBendaoud one of the other packages you are loading is loading the `bidi` package internally, if the advice from Ulrike has not made the error disappear then edit your post to include all your packages you are loading please and perhaps someone can help more.